# PHP: get text after some text

Tags: php

I have this:

`$variable = "El documento ya ha sido registado anteriormente,su estado es aceptado";`

how can I get the text after `'es '`? This should return `aceptado`.

Comment: Show us your best effort, so we can help you on your way

Comment: I don't remember exactly off the top of my head, but PHP has a split function, I think. I think it was called `explode()`.

Comment: A regular expression will work easily. Or you can use `strpos()` to search for `es` and then use `substr()` to get the string after that position.

Comment: This user contribution: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#112707 the function is called `after`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use strpos() to search for 'es '. after getting the postion of 'es ' add 2 to remove 'es' within substr(). I added 2 because total num of char in es is 2

```
<?php
$variable = "El documento ya ha sido registado anteriormente,su estado es aceptado";
$position =strpos($variable , 'es ');
echo substr($variable, $position + 2); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this code and give it a try

```
$variable = "El documento ya ha sido registado anteriormente,su estado es aceptado";
$estado = explode("El documento ya ha sido registado anteriormente,su estado es ", $variable);
echo $estado[0];
echo $estado[1]; // aceptado
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Just a note: `$estado[0]` won't contain the delimiter. It will just be an empty string. When using `explode()`, the delimiter will be removed.

Comment: He just wants the string after the delimiter, that's why I thought this could meet his needs.

Comment: Your solution and code is totally valid and does what the OP wants. I'm just commenting on the comment for `echo $estado[0]; // El documento...`. That echo would just echo an empty string, while it looks like you're saying that it would echo the delimiter. :-)

Comment: Oh, my bad, I just wrote that so the OP knows that he had to pick the $estado[1]. I'll edit that part now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$variable = "El documento ya ha sido registado anteriormente,su estado es aceptado";
$estado = explode("es ", $variable);
echo $estado[0];
echo $estado[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. A regular expression is one way, you can do it multiple ways with `explode()` or you can use `strpos()` with `substr()`. I'm sure there are other clever ways too.

For this example, we'll be using `explode()` to separate the string into an array of words. In my opinion, this is a good idea because you avoid confusion with words that contain the word you're looking for (like you could run into with `strpos()` if you don't pad it with spaces).

Once we have an array of all the words, we use `array_search()` to find the index where the word we're looking for is. We use that position in `array_slice()` to get the part we want, and `implode()` it back into a string.

```php
$variable = "El documento ya ha sido registado anteriormente,su estado es aceptado";

$parts = explode(" ", $variable);
$position = array_search("es", $parts);
echo implode(" ", array_slice($parts, $position + 1)); // +1 to not include the word we're looking for
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/4Mm3f

---

You could also split it by `explode(" es ", $variable)` (note the spaces on each side, to ensure its a word, and not part of another word), and print the last elements.

```php
$variable = "El documento ya ha sido registado anteriormente,su estado es aceptado";

$parts = explode(" es ", $variable);
echo array_pop($parts);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/HZKGZ

---

Or you can use a regular expression to split on the word `es`, note the `\b` for the same reasons as before - we want to ensure its on the word, and not parts of the word.

```php
$variable = "El documento ya ha sido registado anteriormente,su estado es aceptado";

$words = preg_split("/\bes\b/iu", $variable);
echo array_pop($words);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/SqjK5